# Select multi-language как переделать?

Tags: javascript, php, select, multilanguage, мультиязычность

Есть сайт `site.ru`
Сайт на разных языках. Каждая версия языковая в соответствующей папке `/ru/,/en/`
есть код мультиязычности через `select`

```
<select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) self.location='https://site.ru/'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" name="userLanguage" id="userLanguage" style="
    height: 30px;
    background: deepskyblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;width:60px;
">
    <option <?php if ($_GET['lang'] == "ru") { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="ru">RU</option>    
    <option <?php if ($_GET['lang'] == "en") { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="es">EN</option>
</select>
```

Вопросы:

1. Как переделать код, чтобы у каждого языка слева была иконка?
2. Как добавить кнопку "`Применить`", чтоб после выбора языка и нажатия именно этой кнопки был переход на определенную версию сайта, а не как сейчас нажал на язык и сразу переходит?
3. Важно чтобы при наведении на нужный язык не был виден url в браузере, а генерировался кодом (сейчас он генерируется).

Comment: 1) Js/Jquery, 2) Js/Jquery, 3) Как понять не был виден URL в браузере..роутинг чтоль ?

Comment: @sousage1212 я вас понял, но может есть примеры реализации, я даже не представляю как правильно вбить поисковый запрос, чтобы он показал нужную информацию

Comment: Например, https://codepen.io/antonandoff/pen/PmQvBz. Еще можно сделать имитацию <select> через <ul><li>

Comment: @sousage1212 Спасибо, попытался переделать, но не смог там ссылки прописать, пришлось создать здесь новую тему, сможете помочь? Вот она https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367186/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-option-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bb