# Как сделать чтобы у селектора Option переходил на урл?

Tags: javascript, select

Есть код

```js
var langArray = [];
$('.vodiapicker option').each(function() {
  var img = $(this).attr("data-thumbnail");
  var text = this.innerText;
  var value = $(this).val();
  var item = '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" value="' + value + '"/><span>' + text + '</span></li>';
  langArray.push(item);
})

$('#a').html(langArray);

//Set the button value to the first el of the array
$('.btn-select').html(langArray[0]);
$('.btn-select').attr('value', 'ru');

//change button stuff on click
$('#a li').click(function() {
  var img = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
  var value = $(this).find('img').attr('value');
  var text = this.innerText;
  var item = '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" /><span>' + text + '</span></li>';
  $('.btn-select').html(item);
  $('.btn-select').attr('value', value);
  $(".b").toggle();
  //console.log(value);
});

$(".btn-select").click(function() {
  $(".b").toggle();
});

//check local storage for the lang
var sessionLang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
if (sessionLang) {
  //find an item with value of sessionLang
  var langIndex = langArray.indexOf(sessionLang);
  $('.btn-select').html(langArray[langIndex]);
  $('.btn-select').attr('value', sessionLang);
} else {
  var langIndex = langArray.indexOf('ch');
  console.log(langIndex);
  $('.btn-select').html(langArray[langIndex]);
  //$('.btn-select').attr('value', 'ru');
}
```

```css
.vodiapicker {
  display: none;
}

#a {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#a img,
.btn-select img {
  width: 23px;
  height: 17px;
}

#a li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: orange;
}

#a li:hover {
  background-color: #F4F3F3;
  color: black;
}

#a li img {
  margin: 5px;
}

#a li span,
.btn-select li span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* item list */

.b {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.open {
  display: show !important;
}

.btn-select {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #0055c7!important;
  border: 0px;
}

.btn-select li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.btn-select:hover li {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.btn-select:hover {
  background-color: #F4F3F3;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}

.btn-select:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: orange;
}

.lang-select {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

body {
  background-color: #0055c7!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="vodiapicker">
  <option value="ru" class="test" data-thumbnail="/ru.jpg">Russia</option>
  <option value="en" data-thumbnail="/gb.jpg">England</option>
</select>

<div class="lang-select">
  <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
  <div class="b">
    <ul id="a"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе Русского языка переходило на `href="/ru/"`, а английского на `href="/en/"`.
Пытался прописать ссылки не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localstorage раскомментируйте, если нужно

```js
var langArray = [];
$('.vodiapicker option').each(function() {
  var img = $(this).attr("data-thumbnail");
  var text = this.innerText;
  var value = $(this).val();
  var href = $(this).data('href');
  var item = '<li data-href="'+href+'"><img src="' + img + '" alt="" value="' + value + '"/><span>' + text + '</span></li>';
  langArray.push(item);
})

$('#a').html(langArray);

//Set the button value to the first el of the array
$('.btn-select').html(langArray[0]);
$('.btn-select').attr('value', 'ru');
$('.btn-select li').removeAttr('data-href');

//change button stuff on click
$('#a li').click(function() {
  var img = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
  var value = $(this).find('img').attr('value');
  var text = this.innerText;

  var item = '<li><img src="' + img + '" alt="" /><span>' + text + '</span></li>';
  $('.btn-select').html(item);
  $('.btn-select').attr('value', value);
  $(".b").toggle();
  //console.log(value);
});

$(".btn-select").click(function() {
  $(".b").toggle();
});

//check local storage for the lang
/*
var sessionLang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
if (sessionLang) {
  //find an item with value of sessionLang
  var langIndex = langArray.indexOf(sessionLang);
  $('.btn-select').html(langArray[langIndex]);
  $('.btn-select').attr('value', sessionLang);
} else {
  var langIndex = langArray.indexOf('ch');
  console.log(langIndex);
  $('.btn-select').html(langArray[langIndex]);
  //$('.btn-select').attr('value', 'ru');
}
*/

// переход по ссылке
 $('li[data-href]').click(function(){
  window.location.href=$(this).data('href');
})
```

```css
.vodiapicker {
  display: none;
}

#a {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#a img,
.btn-select img {
  width: 23px;
  height: 17px;
}

#a li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: orange;
}

#a li:hover {
  background-color: #F4F3F3;
  color: black;
}

#a li img {
  margin: 5px;
}

#a li span,
.btn-select li span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* item list */

.b {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.open {
  display: show !important;
}

.btn-select {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #0055c7!important;
  border: 0px;
}

.btn-select li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.btn-select:hover li {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.btn-select:hover {
  background-color: #F4F3F3;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}

.btn-select:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: orange;
}

.lang-select {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

body {
  background-color: #0055c7!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="vodiapicker">
  <option value="ru" data-href="/ru/" class="test" data-thumbnail="/ru.jpg">Russia</option>
  <option value="en" data-href="/en/" data-thumbnail="/gb.jpg">England</option>
</select>

<div class="lang-select">
  <button class="btn-select" value=""></button>
  <div class="b">
    <ul id="a"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sousage2012 Спасибо Вам огромное!